# Spring rest and spring web mvc

Tags: spring, rest, model-view-controller

I have an application that has a web front end handled by spring MVC as well as the same services should be exposed as REST services. So the MVC controllers and rest controllers doing nearly the same thing which results in duplicate code. Now, the question is what is the best practice for the current scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refactor your MVC controllers to isolate computation/code services within a `@Service` or `@Component` classes and call those from your rest controller as well as MVC controller to get data out so at the same time you will be able to remove redundancy and you will be able to achieve both functionalities.